# Extract string matching regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I wanted to extract the value between `"@"` and `":"` as well as after `":"` within the following string:

```
str = 
"this is some text

Text@7789347: 4444
some text 
  text   @ 7789348 : 666,555
some text
"
```

Output:

```
"7789347", " 4444"
"7789348", " 666,555"
```

I am using the following regex:

```
(\s)*[t|T][e|E][x|X][t|T](\s)*@(\s)*(\d)*(\s)*:.*
```

I can select the required field, but I don't know how to get the values.

Comment: Do you mean `I don't know how to get the matches`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have to match only floating digits, you can use the `/(?mi)^\s*\btext\b.*?@\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s*:\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)?)$/` regex:

```
str="""this is some text

Text@7789347: 4444
some text 
  text   @ 7789348 : 666,555
some text
"""
puts str.scan(/(?mi)^\s*\btext\b.*?@\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s*:\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)?)$/)
```

Output of [the demo](https://ideone.com/yR62zl):

```
7789347
4444
7789348
666,555
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. is it not possible to match complete string in format "Text@7789347: 4444" using regex than extract the value 7789347 and 4444 from it instead of just parsing digits? There can be other instance which can contain digits without "Text" in starting of line.

Comment: You still want to extract just the numbers, right? Only the paragraph must start with "Text"? But what is the ending delimiter?

Comment: Without knowing where to stop, knowing just the starting delimiter will not help.

Comment: yes, you are right. "Text" will be there in starting. There will be nothing at the end of the line. For eg: after 4444 or 666,555 there will be nothing in the same line.

Answer (score 1):

You can `scan` it like this:

```
str.each_line{ |line|
  a = line.scan(/@(.*):(.*)$/)
  puts a[0].inspect if !a.empty?
}
# ["7789347", " 4444"]
# [" 7789348 ", " 666,555"]
```

Comment: Thanks Shivam. is it not possible to match the complete line using regex in  the question and then extract the value.

Comment: yeah its possible but this approach is much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

To get the values you can use: `@\s*(.*?)\s*:\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)*)`

```
if line =~ /@\s*(.*?)\s*:\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)*)/
   match1 = $~[1]
   match2 = $~[2]
else
   match = ""
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Below Regex may help you:

```
@\s*(\d+)\s*:\s*([0-9,]*)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kJ2wT5/2)